# how to increase the data transfer speed from oracle 10g into jsp pages using scriplet

Tags: java, jsp, oracle10g

I have incorporated my jsp pages with an autosuggest features, and to make the autosuggest functioning, it has to make an array of the data to be suggested using scriplet.

My issues is, as i import the data from oracle 10G, the time to complete the import of the data into the pages, is about 20-40 second.

Hence, is there any way to increase the speed of data transfer i already try the indexing method but it does help with the time, and the number of data in the table is about 6K .

Can the oracle pro, suggest any ways to solve this issues.. hehe =D

And here is the sample of my program :-

Function in my autosuggest.java, to retrieve and filter the data from my db.

```
    public List getVendorName() throws Exception
{
    List temp=null; 
    Database db=null;
    String tempVar, tempVar2;
    boolean tempVar3, tempVar4;
    int counter=0;
    try {
        db = PersistenceHelper.beginTransaction();
        JDOQuery queryFund = new JDOQuery(db,Trader.class);
        queryFund.setFilter(PersistenceHelper.getOrganizationFilter("organization"));
        temp = new ArrayList();
        QueryResults results = queryFund.execute();
        while(results.hasMore())
        {
            Trader trader   = (Trader) results.next();
            tempVar     = "\""+trader.getName()+"\"";
            tempVar2    = trader.getTraderType();
            tempVar3    = trader.getRegTraderStatus();
            tempVar4    = trader.getMainTraderStatus();
            if(!tempVar2.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
            {
                if( (tempVar3 == true) && (tempVar4 == true))
                {
                    tempVar     = tempVar.replace("\n", "");
                    temp.add(counter,tempVar); counter++;               
                }
            }           
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }       
    finally{
        PersistenceHelper.closeTransaction(db, false);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Function in my jsp page. to retrieve the data from autosuggest.java;

```
    function getVendorName()
{
    var temp = new Array();
    <%
        AutoSuggest as = new AutoSuggest();
        List tempList = as.getVendorName();
        for(int i=0; i<tempList.size(); i++)
        {
            Strinmg tempVar  = (String) tempList.get(i);
            %> temp[<%=i%>] = <%=tempVar%>; <%
        }
    %>
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to try would be to do the filtering by trader type and status in the database query ... rather on the Java side.  The way you are currently doing this will entail pulling large numbers of `Trader` objects from the database.  I expect most of them are then being discarded by your Java code.

Comment: Thank for the answer, but can you guide me on how to filter the data in the db. Because i am really new with oracle. Is it using queries??

Comment: "Is it using queries?" - I guess so, and specifically, using query filters ... though I'm not a JDO expert.  Take a look at what your `PersistenceHelper.getOrganizationFilter(...)` method does.

Comment: Ok thanx.. i'll take a look at what does the method do. Ouh,one more question, the table that i am currently connect have about 30 columns in it. Is it possible if i want to import only 6 columns of data before i filter it???... thnx again... =D